# Updating/Reassigning a Value in Java

Tags: java

So I've run into a kind of ridiculous predicament with one of my new projects. One of my assignments is to develop a game, and the player is given the option to be able to heal their hero a maximum of four times to max health. I've assigned a health value, assigned a command value so it recognizes when the player wants to heal, but I'm kind of stuck on how to limit the user to using the heal command only four times and how to restore their health back to full.

I was reading a different post on stackoverflow that seemed to have some relevance to my issue, although I couldn't quite figure out how to adjust it to my needs.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
```

Any advice or even direct help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit: Four times they can heal maximum in one game session. So once they use the heal command once, they can only use it three times, and so on and so on. The user inputs an integer in order to call the heal command up, in this case I prompt them for a decision and they simply input the number 0.

Comment: So you need a heal counter that starts on 4 and goes down by 1 on every `heal` method?

Comment: You haven't given enough context for us to understand the question.  How does a player "ask" to heal?  What does the limit "four times" mean... per session? Per minute? Per hour? Per lifetime?  What is the definition of the character's "health"?  Is it a single number, or does it have other attributes?  Etc.... lots of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what i can understand from your question is that you want the above code to be executed a maximum of 4 times i.e. if the user calls the method 1 time execute it, 2 times execute it and so on... But if it is called the fifth time you don't want the code to be executed.
This can be achieved by maintaining a counter for example as shown below

```
public class Q
{

public static void main(String[] n)
{
    Q1 ob =new Q1();
    ob.myMethod();
    System.out.println("One time");

    ob.myMethod();
    System.out.println("two time");

    ob.myMethod();
    System.out.println("three time");

    ob.myMethod();
    System.out.println("Fourth time");

    ob.myMethod();

}
}
```

As you can see i have called the method 5 times. Now lets see how to restrict the user from getting or making only 4 calls to the method

```
class Q1
{
int counter=0;
public void myMethod()
{
    if(counter<4)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        do 
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
            while (!sc.hasNextInt()) 
            {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
    } while (number <= 0);
    System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
    counter++;
}

else
{
    System.out.println("A maximum of 4 times of healing is allowed");
}

}
 }
```